# Calculate time difference between 2 times - Logic issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a string in the format `Tue May 22 2012 11.00 pm` . Now i need to convert this into `NSDate` and then get the current Date and time form `NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate today];`.

Then find the time difference in `Seconds` between the 2.

I am unable to solve this, help me please

Comment: If it's local time, you can't. For example, on the day we set our clocks back an hour, there are some times that repeat twice. At minimum, you also need to know whether the time specified is daylight time or standard time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a string in the format Tue May 22 2012 11.00 pm . Now i need to convert this into NSDate

Ok for this part you need an `NSDateFormatter``

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"EEE MM dd yyyy hh.mm a"];
NSDate *dateFromString =[df dateFromString:yourString];
```

This was the first part.

Now for the

> Then find the time difference in Seconds between the 2.

```
NSTimeIntervall diffInSeconds = [dateFromString timeIntervalSinceNow];
```

This will calculate the seconds between the `dateFromString`and now.

For mor information about working with date and time in cocoa I highly recomment Ole Begemenans ["Working with Date and Time in Cocoa Series"](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/11/working-with-date-and-time-in-cocoa-part-1/)

Comment: I tried this `NSDate *dateFromString =[df dateFromString:@"Mon May 21 2012 11.00 pm"];` but the output i get is `Mon 12 26 2011 11.00 PM`.  Incorrect date gets displayed.

Comment: NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"EEE MM dd YYYY hh.mm a"];
    df.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];

    NSDate *dateFromString =[df dateFromString:@"Mon May 21 2012 11.00 pm"];
    
    NSTimeInterval diffInSeconds = [dateFromString timeIntervalSinceNow];
    
    
    NSLog(@"%@", [df stringFromDate:dateFromString]);

My code

Comment: `2011-12-26 23:00:00 +0000
` I get a 2011 date. But what i entered in the String is a 2012 date

Comment: `2011-12-26 23:00:00 +0000
` same as before.

Comment: I think this works `EEE MMM dd yyyy hh.mm a`. Make the YYYY in lower case.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful. i was stuck in this for days.

Comment: I get Minus value for `    NSLog(@"Time difference in seconds %i ", (int)diffInSeconds); 
` . Output was `Time difference in seconds  -638998` IS this correct ?

Answer (score 2):

Use NSDateFormatter to turn your string date Tue May 22 2012 11.00 pm to an NSDate. You will also need to set the timezone of your string date in your nsdateformatter.

Example:

```
    NSDateFormatter * frmt;
    frmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    frmt.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    frmt.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
```

You will need to use the dateFormat that correspond to your string.

Then you get your nsdate using

```
[frmt dateFromString:(NSString *)dateString]
```

then you can compare the two NSDate using `-timeIntervalSinceDate`

Answer (score 1):

Convert both to `time_t` (probably with [`mktime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mktime)) then subtract. In theory you should use [`difftime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/difftime) to compute the difference, but in reality `time_t` on most typical systems (almost certainly including MacOS) is an integer number of seconds since an epoch (Midnight January 1, 1970 for POSIX), so subtraction works fine.

There are, of course, a few wrinkles from daylight savings time, some of which create unresolvable ambiguities.

Comment: The general answer is: If at all possible, realize that you've painted yourself into a corner and change the design so that you don't have this problem in the first place.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: yes, generally. As I'm sure you already know, there really isn't any way to get an answer that's guaranteed correct, at least for most local times, so that's about as good as it gets.

Answer (score 1):

`-dateFromString:` method of [`NSDateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class should help.

Then `-timeIntervalSinceNow` of `NSDate` gives the time interval. You don't need intermediate step `[NSDate today]`.